# Press multiple keys at once

Tags: python, pygame

I am trying to make a two person game where each person moves an object but if one person is moving their object the other can't. Here is my code.

```
running = True
while running:
    if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
        if (event.key == 276):
            bat2.rect.x -= 2
        if (event.key == 275):
            bat2.rect.x += 2
        if (event.key == 97):
            bat1.rect.x -= 1
        if (event.key == 100):
            bat1.rect.x += 1
```

Each bat is a different object. Is there a way?

Comment: `pygame.KEYDOWN` always sends only last pressed key - when button change state from "not-pressed" to "pressed" but it isn't created when you hold pressed key. You should use `pygame.key.get_pressed()` to check key when you hold it pressed.

Comment: @furas That's a very good point but he also is only checking the most recent event which means that he will not see multiple keypresses at once.

Comment: @Chachmu OP doesn't use `pygame.event.get()' so OP shouldn't get any key press - even first. So I assumediOP used `pygame.event.get()` somewhere in this loop - but maybe you are right and OP used `pygame.event.get()` only once before `while`

Answer (score 2):

To get multiple keys in `PyGame` you can do

```
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
            running = False

    # --- after events ---

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT]: # 276
        bat2.rect.x -= 2
    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]: # 275
        bat2.rect.x += 2
    if keys[pygame.K_a]: # 97
        bat1.rect.x -= 1
    if keys[pygame.K_d]: # 100
        bat1.rect.x += 1
```

You use `pygame.event.get():` get events and it will update valus in special list which you can get with `pygame.key.get_pressed()` and then you can check which keys are hold pressed - but you have to do it after `events`, not inside `pygame.KEYDOWN` which is created only when button change state from "not-pressed" to "pressed" but not when you hold it pressed.

---

Using `KEYDOWN` you should do it this way

```
bat2_move_left = False
bat2_move_right = False
bat1_move_left = False
bat1_move_right = False

while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT():
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: # 276
                bat2_move_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: # 275
                bat2_move_right = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: # 97
                bat1_move_left = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_d: # 100
                bat1_move_right = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT: # 276
                bat2_move_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT: # 275
                bat2_move_right = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_a: # 97
                bat1_move_left = False
            if event.key == pygame.K_d: # 100
                bat1_move_right = False

    # --- after events ---

    if bat2_move_left:
        bat2.rect.x -= 2
    if bat2_move_right:
        bat2.rect.x += 2
    if bat1_move_left:
        bat1.rect.x -= 1
    if bat1_move_right:
        bat1.rect.x += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through every event that you receive each loop, not just the first one. Try moving your `if event.type` statements into another loop like this:

```
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if (event.key == 276):
                bat2.rect.x -= 2
            if (event.key == 275):
                bat2.rect.x += 2
```

Answer (score -1):

In libgdx I usually use:

```
for(int i=0; i<2; i++)
{
If(Gdx.input.isTouched(i))
//do something
}
```

The "i<2" allows two touches in screen: i=0  and i=1.